# how to crawl and download all pdf files from html link?

Tags: php, dom, pdf, web-crawler

This is my code to crawl all pdf links but it doesn't work. How to download from those links and save to a folder on my computer?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url = 'http://example.com';
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('invalid url');

//extrack pdf links
foreach($html->find('a[href=[^"]*\.pdf]') as $element)
echo $element->href.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: it looks like you have a typo, in the foreach loop, $htnl should be $html. If that wasn't in your oriiginal code, what exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: @ggreiner in my ori code, there's no typo, sorry. i miss typo here. blank result in my web page

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($htnl->find('a[href=[^"]*\.pdf]') as element)
           ^---typo. should be an 'm'        ^---typo. need a $ here
```

How does your code "not work", other than because of above typo?

Comment: ups, sorry, in my original code, there's no typo -.-. it doesn't work, blank result in my web page

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into into phpquery? 
http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 0):

More simple solution here will be:

```
foreach ($html->find('a[href$=pdf]') as $element)
```

https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm

> [attribute$=value]    Matches elements that have the specified attribute
> and it ends with a certain value.